# What is the equivalent of Content Provider(Android) in Xamarin development

Tags: android, windows, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-contentprovider

I am developing an application which requires the use of content provider on Android and Windows platform. The reason I am using content provider is that I want to use that data in another application and if there are any changes in the database, the other application is informed. I am using Xamarin platform. But could anyone tell me what can I use for Content Provider if that application has to also work on Windows ?

Comment: your answer might be [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/platform_features/intro_to_content_providers/part_3_-_creating_a_custom_contentprovider/)

Comment: You're asking to use the contentprovider which is a class on Android, on windows. Windows does not have this class, so it won't work of course.

Answer (score 0):

@softlion : that is the whole question about, I am trying to look for an equivalent of content provider on Windows. Since Xamarin offers same backend code in C# for Windows, Android, Apple, so if I could use the same code for both the applications it would be very efficient